# Range query in Elasticsearch_dsl by integer field

Tags: django, elasticsearch, elasticsearch-dsl-py

I used `elasticsearch-dsl==5.2.0`, `elasticsearch==5.3.0` and `Django==1.8.15`.

**Django model**:

```
class Item(models.Model):
    price = models.DecimalField(default=0)

    def to_search(self):
        return DocItem(
            meta={'id': self.id},
            price=self.price
        )
```

**DocType class**:

```
class DocItem(DocType):
    price = Integer()
```

**FacetedSearch class**:

```
class ItemSearch(FacetedSearch):
    index = 'item'
    doc_types = [DocItem, ]
    fields = ['price']
```

When I need to search all items with `price == 5.0`, I do the next:

```
search = ItemSearch().search()
result = search.filter('match', price=5.0).execute()
```

**Question**:

How can I search all items with price in range:  1.0 < price <= 5.0 ?

Answer (score 18, accepted):

You can do it like this:

```
search = ItemSearch().search()
result = search.filter('range', price={'gt': 1, 'lte': 5.0}).execute()
```

Comment: Where I can read about existing filter types, like `'range'` and other params like `'gt'`, `'lte'`? What is it the syntax?

Comment: Also you can see the full query DSL in the official documentation at https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/query-dsl.html

Comment: How to query all items that price are in the array, like: `price__in=[30, 10, 20, ...]`?

Comment: That should be a different question in my opinion

Comment: For a question in the commens about how to query items in an array you can use 'terms', see https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/query-dsl-terms-query.html

Comment: how can we specify size here

Comment: @lazarus you can find the pagination doc [here](https://elasticsearch-dsl.readthedocs.io/en/latest/search_dsl.html#pagination)